# ArrayList with null values in Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I got a issue that is taking my sleep away. I've got some ArrayList in my Controller, but when I execute my method, its become null, but in my JPADAO, the values are right, I don't know what to do anymore.

**Controller**

```
private List<Produto> produtos;
@Autowired
private ProdutoService produtoService;
public void produtoPorCategoria(Long id) throws ServiceException {
    setProdutos(produtoService.produtoPorCategoria(id));
}
//getters and setters
```

**ProdutoService**

```
@Override
public List<Produto> produtoPorCategoria(Long id) throws ServiceException {
    try {
        produtoDAO.produtoPorCategoria(id);
    } catch (DAOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**PRodutoJPADAO**

```
@Override
public List<Produto> produtoPorCategoria(Long id) throws DAOException {
    TypedQuery<Produto> query = em.createNamedQuery("produto.produtoPorCategoria", Produto.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**My query**

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "produto.produtoPorCategoria", query = "SELECT p FROM Produto p, Categoria c WHERE p.categoria.id  = c.id AND p.ativo = TRUE AND c.id = :id"),
```

When I debugged and  the values are right, my queries are correct and the values in JPADAO, service are correct too, but when I do the setProdutos, the Arraylist becomes null, I know the error is in the controller, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning null at the end of the produtoPorCategoria method in the service..after the dao call.produtoPorCategoria is always returning null regardless of anything done in the service call.

Comment: You're right, I can't believe that I didn't see that, I created a ArrayList<Produto> and it received the value from DAO and returned it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I did that, and works

```
List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        produtos = produtoDAO.produtoPorCategoria(id);
    } catch (DAOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProdutoServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return produtos;
```